# Debian 8.1 with Uboot bootloader cannot run FSCK on reboot

Tags: linux, debian, init-script, fsck, u-boot

I am running Debian 8.1 on an SD card on a Banana PI with U-boot bootloader.

I'm trying to force my system to run `fsck` on reboot, but no matter what I do, nothing happens. Here are what I have tried so far:

- Set `FSCKFIX=yes` inside `/etc/defaults/rcS`
- `touch /forcefsck` and `reboot`
- Update `/proc/cmdline` to include `fsck.mode=force` and `fsck.repair=yes` (this was done by `cp` the file to another location, and then `mount -n --bind` to it

No matter what, nothing happens. When I look at the log file (`/var/logs/fsck/checkfs`) there are no entries.

I tried creating my own file to run on bootup that would call `fsck` and I looked at my own log file and all I see is `fsck from util-linux 2.25.2`. I changed the init script to explicitly run on the drive (i.e. `fsck -yf /dev/mmcblk0p2`) and then the log file said the system is aborting because the drive is already mounted. FYI, this init script is running before `checkfs` or `checkroot` run!

I would really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this recently on the BananaPi myself. It's likely your booting with Systemd so setting `FSCKFIX=yes` inside `/etc/defaults/rcS`

Won't help you. Also `/proc` is a [virtual filesytem](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/), so changes will disappear between reboots.

Setting those kernel options are correct for `systemd`, but you need to [append them to the boot args](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxKernelArgs).

In `/boot/boot.cmd` I appended `fsck.repair=yes` to the end of the `setenv bootargs`:

```
setenv bootargs "console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_no_mali_mem_reserve sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 panic=10 consoleblank=0 enforcing=0 loglevel=${verbosity} fsck.repair=yes"
```

It's important to note you need to re-generate the `/boot/boot.cmd` before they'll appear using the following command (it's at printed at the end of `/boot/boot.cmd`)

```
mkimage -C none -A arm -T script -d /boot/boot.cmd /boot/boot.scr
```

You can can confirm it applied after rebooting with `cat`:

```
~# cat /proc/cmdline 
console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_no_mali_mem_reserve sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 panic=10 consoleblank=0 enforcing=0 loglevel=1 fsck.repair=yes
```